# Failcallback breaks multiple then

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having

```
service.method().then(donecallback1, failcallback1).then(callback2)
```

assume that there was error and `failcallback1` was launched, will `callback2` then be omitted?

Other words, will `callback2` be fired only when `donecallback1` was fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what value is returned by `failcallback1` or `donecallback1`.

But assuming they are not returning anything, the `calback2` will not be fired if the promise is rejected.

But if they return a promise the second `then` will be evaluated based on the returned promises state

Comment: is promise rejected if failcallback1 or donecallback1 is doin'g nothing?